# How does Plot work?

Tags: plotting, implementation-details

I considered the following function:

```
sin[x_] := Module[{},
  Print["x=", x];
  Sin[x]
]
```

in *Mathematica*. Next, I tried to plot it using:

```
Plot[sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Surprisingly, the first three lines of output are:

```
x=0.000128356
x=t
x=1.28228*10^-7
```

Can someone explain this behavior? In this case it doesn't cause a problem, but in my "real" case it does.

#### Summary

acl's answer below offers, at its very beginning a solution to the specific problem. In very-short, the reason that this `x=t` appears is hidden somewhere in the way *Mathematica* evaluates the functions. The answers below provide interesting insight into the way it works.

The interested reader *should* read all the answers and details below, they are invaluable, although might be behind the reach of some of the readers (like, partially, in my case).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the problem is that a symbolic argument is passed, you can avoid it thus:

```
ClearAll[sin];
sin[x_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  Print[x];
  Sin[x]
  ]
```

which simply defines `sin` so that it only matches for numeric arguments.

To see what it does, try `sin[3.]` and `sin[x]` and notice that the second evaluates to itself, as the definition above does not match.

You can also see what values of `x` are being evaluated by
    ClearAll[sin];
    sin[x_] := Module[{},
      Sow[x];
      Sin[x]
      ]
and then `Plot[sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]; // Reap`. `x` now appears.

However,

```
lst = {};
ClearAll[sin2];
sin2[x_] := Module[{},
  AppendTo[lst, x];
  Sin[x]
  ]
```

and then `Plot[sin2[x], {x, 0, 10}];` and then we have no symbols in `lst` at the end.

EDIT: The explanation for this discrepancy between `Sow`/`Reap` and using a list is explained by Leonid in the comments. To test his proposal, I tried using a `Bag` instead of a list (this is undocumented, see Daniel Lichtblau's [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica/6795762#6795762)) as follows:

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Internal`"];
lst = Bag[];
sin3[x_] := Module[{},
  StuffBag[lst, x];
  Sin[x]
]
```

followed by `Plot[sin3[x], {x, 0, 10}];`. We now inspect the contents of the bag by `BagPart[lst, All]` and observe that there is indeed a symbol `x` in there.

Presumably it has to do with the way scoping constructs interact with the evaluations performed by `AppendTo` and `StuffBag`.

EDIT 2 (by Leonid Shifrin)

We can also demonstrate the same using more usual tools. In particular, instead of a `Bag` that has its own API, we can use any `HoldAll` wrapper (just not a list), and then the code for the function itself we need not change at all:

```
In[51]:= 
ClearAll[h];
SetAttributes[h,HoldAll];
lst=h[];
ClearAll[sin2];
sin2[x_]:=Module[{},AppendTo[lst,x];Sin[x]]

In[58]:= 
Plot[sin2[x],{x,0,10}];
lst//Short

Out[59]//Short= h[0.000204286,x,<<1131>>,9.99657]
```

This clarifies what happens. The `x` inside `List` is substituted by the  numerical value as a result of evaluation in `AppendTo`, roughly as follows:

```
In[60]:= 
Clear[x];
lst = {0.000204,x};
Block[{x = 2.04*10^(-7)},
  AppendTo[lst,x]];
lst

Out[63]= {0.000204,2.04*10^-7,2.04*10^-7}
```

while the `HoldAll` attribute of `h` prevents the evaluation from happening (this will be more clear yet if we write `AppendTo` as `lst = Append[lst,x]`. It is the evaluation of the r.h.s. (`Append`), where `lst` is evaluated and `x` is substituted by its bound value). For `h`, `x` inside it does not evaluate, and is therefore kept symbolic. Similar thing happens with `Reap`-`Sow`, although the mechanism `Reap`-`Sow` is using to store the results is obviously different (but, whatever it is, it bypasses the main evaluation loop, and that is what matters).

EDIT 3 (acl):

There was a question in the comments as to why the numbers returned by `Sow/Reap` are not in ascending order. The reason is that Plot apparently uses an adaptive algorithm, in the same spirit as one does in adaptive integration (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature, for instance).

Do `Plot[sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]; // Reap // Last // Last // ListPlot` to see it spend more effort at the turning points:

[image]

If you add the option `MaxRecursion -> 0` to the Plot command, the algorithm does not subdivide steps that it deems inaccurate and the values are in order:

[image]

Maybe it is clearer to do it interactively. Let us play with `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`:

```
ClearAll[sin];
sin[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; Sin[x])

Manipulate[
 pts = ((plt = Plot[
          sin[x],
          {x, 0, 10},
          PlotStyle \[Rule] {Red, Thin},
          PlotPoints \[Rule] n,
          MaxRecursion \[Rule] m
          ];) // Reap // Last // Last);

 Show[
  {
   ListPlot[
    Transpose@{pts, Sin[pts]},
    PlotMarkers \[Rule] {Automatic, 3}
    ],
   plt
   }
  ],
 {m, Range[0, 5]},
 {{n, 10}, Range[1, 50]}
 ]
```

`m` is the value of `MaxRecursion`, `n` that of `PlotPoints`. The plot shows the resulting plot of `Sin` and, overlaid, the points that have been evaluated to produce it. Play with the numbers and it should become clear what is happening: `PlotPoints` tells `Plot` how many points to evaluate initially, `MaxRecursion` tells `Plot` how many times it may subdivide the regions thus defined if necessary (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572183/strange-sinx-graph-in-mathematica/4572266#4572266) for a discussion of what "necessary" means).

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there is more added to the puzzle than solved :D  The `Evaluated` option of `Plot` is of relevance as well (it can be `True` or `False` or `Automatic`).  I can't explain your results either.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes I tried that too (I believe I first heard about this option from you). Didn't help to explain much, so I thought I'd avoid further muddling the waters.

Comment: can you reproduce the OPs results?

Comment: @rcollyer yes...

Comment: I was hoping that his results were not reproducible, then your lack of findings with `Sow` would make sense. Now I'm just as confused as everyone else.

Comment: "Plot[sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]; // Reap" gives a symbol x in the second position of the output list in my case.

Comment: @Sjoerd OK, I tried a couple more times and it didn't. Then I quite the kernel and tried again and, lo! `x` now appears in the second place! I don't know if quitting the kernel did it or if I was blind... So that answers it then (apart from `lst`).

Comment: no symbols in lst though. Puzzling this.

Comment: The first number seems to be left boundary of the plot range + some epsilon. I always this was some "dipping your toe into the water" test or so, perhaps used to calculate the derivative at the start.  I assumed the symbolic evaluation occurred to calculate a symbolic derivative (or to test if there's one). But this doesn't explain the Sow/Append differences at all.

Comment: @Sjoerd, rcollyer Here is what I think is happening. The crucial thing is that at some point, the *binding* of symbol `x` to a numerical value is happening. But first, symbolic argument `x` is tried (presumably as a part of an attempt to symbolically preprocess the function). At that point, symbol `x` *does* get into the list. To see that, use `sin2[x_] :=
 Module[{}, AppendTo[lst, x];  If[MatchQ[lst, {___, _Symbol, ___}], Print[lst]];  Sin[x]]` (for example). Then, I suspect, `Plot` us using dynamic scoping (like `Block`) to localize the variable `x`. Therefore, once numeric computation ...

Comment: @Sjoerd continuing ... starts, `x` gets dynamically *bound* to a given numerical value (first, the first one, etc). The next `AppendTo`, being within that dynamic scope, evaluates `lst = {firstnumber, x}` to `lst = {firstnumber, secondnumber}`, where `secondnumber` is what `x` is bound to now. After that, we get purely numerical list of course. The reason that this does not happen with `Reap`- `Sow` is that they use a different mechanism to store results, which is immune to the dynamic scope imposed by `Plot`. At least, this is what I think is happening.

Comment: @Leonid that could explain it indeed.

Comment: @acl I think this, if correct, complements you answer. But you gave the most important part -  advice about `NumericQ`, so +1.

Comment: @Leonid I think you're right: I tried using a `Bag` instead of a `List` and it does appear to keep the `x` in place. Let me edit my answer to add that. I suggest you add the discussion above in a separate answer.

Comment: @acl I only answered the specific question, while you formulated the puzzle. Formulating a question right is generally more important than finding an answer, so I would prefer if you could simply edit your post and incorporate my notes there in some way. I could then perhaps edit it, if something else comes to my mind in this regard.

Comment: @Leonid OK, if you prefer it this way. I'll edit my answer later today to incorporate your comments (or you can also do it at any time if you want).

Comment: This answer, and the following discussion are somehow beyond my mathematica's scope. I can't say I understand the reason why this happens. Actually, I have more questions then answers here... For example, I just realized that the in the `Sow-Reap` case, returned values are *NOT* in an increasing order. This surprised me. Can someone summarize the issue? In any case, thanks for the intensive discussion.

Comment: @Dror what is it you do not understand? why x appears, or why your function gets evaluated with symbolic arguments? the first is (presumably) `Plot` trying to work out if the function has a symbolic form, so that it can eg compile it. the second may be fixed by adding NumericQ after x_. I've added a section as to why the numbers aren't in increasing order (couldn't fit it here).

Answer (score 34):

It is interesting to compare the `Plot` algorithms of *Mathematica* 5.2 and *Mathematica* 6+. Based on acl's code:

In *Mathematica* 5.2 we get:

```
Plot[Sow[x]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
    DisplayFunction -> (Null &)] // Reap // Last // Last // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica 5.2 output]

In *Mathematica* 7.0.1:

```
Plot[Sow[x]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Reap // Last // Last // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica 7.0.1 output]

One can see that *Mathematica* 5.2 computes only 105 points while version 7.0.1 computes 567 points (including one symbolic evaluation). At the same time, the plots produced by two versions are visually indistinguishable. Only very careful comparison reveals tiny differences. Here is `ListPlot` of both sets of points: generated by version 5.2 (dashed black line) and version 7.0.1 (blue line) with resolution 600 dpi (**click to enlarge!**):

[image: comparison]

---

---

### Edit

In *Mathematica* 5.2 the default value for [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/PlotPoints) is 25 and for [`PlotDivision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/PlotDivision) is 30 as documented in [Section 1.9.2 of "The *Mathematica* Book" for version 5.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-1.9.2). I do not know where the default value for `PlotPoints` in version 7 is documented but we can find it by setting `MaxRecursion` to zero:

```
In[1]:= Cases[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0], 
                            Line[x_] :> Length[x], Infinity]

Out[1]= {50}
```

From the other side, using `Reap` and `Sow` we get different value:

```
In[2]:= Select[
  Plot[Sow[x], {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0]; // Reap // 
    Last // First, NumericQ] // Length

Out[2]= 51
```

For *Mathematica* 5.2 both methods give the same result (25). It seems that in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 the first point is calculated just for the check that the objective function gives numerical value for numerical argument but this point is not included in the final plot:

```
In[4]:= Complement[
 Plot[Sow[x], {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 25] // 
    Reap // Last // First, 
 Cases[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 25], 
   Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1, All, 1]]]

Out[4]= {0.000417083, x}
```

### Edit 2

In *Mathematica* 7 increasing `MaxRecursion` just adds new layers of points to the `ListPlot`:

```
v7points[r_] := 
  Module[{i = 1}, 
   Last@Last@
     Reap@Plot[Sow[{i++, x}]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
       MaxRecursion -> r]];
v7plot = ListPlot[Join[{v7points[0]}, 
   Complement[v7points[# + 1], v7points[#]] & /@ Range[0, 10]], 
  PlotMarkers -> (Graphics`PlotMarkers[] /. {m_, s_} :> {m, s/2}), 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[60, "ColorList"]]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

In *Mathematica* 5.2 we have `PlotDivision` instead of `MaxRecursion`:

```
v5Points[d_] := 
 krn5Eval[Module[{i = 1}, 
   Last@Last@
     Reap@Plot[Sow[{i++, x}]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
       PlotDivision -> d, DisplayFunction -> (Null &)]]]
v5plot = ListPlot[v5Points[#] & /@ Range[1, 9], 
  PlotMarkers -> (Graphics`PlotMarkers[] /. {m_, s_} :> {m, s/2}), 
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[60, "ColorList"]]
```

(here `krn5Eval[expr]` is [a `MathLink` function which evaluates `expr` in the kernel of *Mathematica* 5 from inside of *Mathematica* 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983301/executing-code-in-v-5-2-kernel-from-within-v-7-01-session-through-mathlink))

[image: screenshot]

From the point of view of the number of evaluations in the case of plotting of `Sin[x]` `PlotPoints -> 2, PlotDivision -> 30` is roughly equivalent to `PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 5`. So we can compare:

```
v7Ps = Last@
   Last@Reap@
     Plot[Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
      MaxRecursion -> 5];
v5Ps = Last@
   Last@krn5Eval[
     Reap@Plot[Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]; Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 2, 
       DisplayFunction -> (Null &), PlotDivision -> 30]];
ListLinePlot[Sort /@ {v7Ps, v5Ps}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, Dashed}}]
```

[image: plot]
**(click to enlarge!)**

---

### Edit 3

Both algorithms have the same drawback: adaptive refinement is made by minimizing the angles at the nodes connecting the segments of the approximating polyline, but if a corner was once close enough to 180 degrees (180 degrees minus this angle is less than the corresponding parameter: `MaxBend` or `ControlValue`), the corresponding node is dropped and no longer checked. Here is an illustration of what happens in version 5.2:

[image: screenshot]

The same case for *Mathematica* 6+ was already investigated by Yaroslav Bulatov: "[Strange Sin[x] graph in *Mathematica*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572183/strange-sinx-graph-in-mathematica/4572266#4572266)."

In such cases increasing of `MaxRecursion` in MMa 6+ does nothing since the node is already dropped from the list of nodes to check. In *Mathematica* 5 the problem is more subtle: changing any of the control parameters (`PlotPoints`, `MaxBend`, `PlotDivision`) shifts all sample points and as a result the problematic node disappear but now it may emerge in another place. And increasing `PlotDivision` will not reduce the probability to face this problem again if you have already faced it. The only reliable solution is to considerably increase `PlotPoints`.

### Edit 4

The `MaxBend` option of `Plot` in *Mathematica* 5 has a completely equivalent undocumented sub-sub-option `ControlValue` in *Mathematica* 6+ with only difference: the latter should be specified in radians while the former in degrees. At the same time, *Mathematica* 6+ still has the old `MaxBend` option moved inside of `Method` option. I have found it accidentally by evaluating

```
Plot[x,{x,0,1},MaxBend->1,PlotDivision->1];
MaxBend::deprec: MaxBend->1 is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions of Mathematica. Use Method->{MaxBend->1} instead.
PlotDivision::deprec: PlotDivision->1 is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions of Mathematica. Use Method->{PlotDivision->1} instead. >>
```

I have tested it and found that the following two ways to specify `MaxBend` are completely equivalent in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 and 8.0.4:

```
In[1]:= With[{maxBend = 5}, 
 First@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-110, -90}, All}, Method -> {MaxBend -> maxBend}] ===
   First@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-110, -90}, All}, 
    Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> maxBend*\[Degree]}}]]

Out[1]= True
```

When these options are specified together the `ControlValue` is used.

Note that `MaxBend` in version 5 by has default value `10.` (degrees) while in version 6+ it has default value `5*Degree` (radians). The less this value - the more precise plot will be generated, so in really it is not correct to compare these algorithms with no attention to this option.

One important feature (bug?) of `Plot` in *Mathematica* 6+ is that it does not stop adding new levels of recursion when the `"ControlValue"` condition is already satisfied:

```
l[mr_] := 
 Length@Reap[Plot[Sow[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> mr]][[2, 1]]
ListPlot[l /@ Range[1, 15], Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"MaxRecursion", "Number of evaluation points "}, 
 PlotLabel -> StandardForm@HoldForm[Plot[x, {x, -Pi, Pi}]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

At the same time, in *Mathematica* 5 `Plot` stops recursion when bend angles become less than `MaxBend`:

[image: screenshot]

---

### The danger of `PlotRange -> Automatic`

With `PlotRange -> Automatic` edge points where the clipping takes place come not from evaluation of the objective function but from linear interpolation of the actual evaluation points (not all of which are included in the final plot):

```
f[x_Real] := (Sow[{x, 1/x}] // Last);
r = Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]];
cpt = Complement[Flatten[Cases[r[[1]], Line[x_] :> x, Infinity], 1], r[[2, 1]]]
```

> ```
> {{-0.08742340731847899`, -11.441210582842762`},
>  {-0.0003010859168438364`, -11.441210582842762`},
>  {-0.0002994911120048032`, 11.37677150741012`},
>  {0.08796546946877723`, 11.37677150741012`}}
> ```

```
Interpolation[r[[2, 1]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][cpt[[{1, -1}, 1]]]
```

> ```
> {-11.441210582842762`, 11.37677150741012`}
> ```

Comment: very cool, +1. could you repeat this with both versions and with explicit setting for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`?

Comment: It looks like v5.2 steps through the range until it finds interesting (big 2nd derivative) parts - in this case the turning points - it then investigates that part in more detail until moving on. Versions >= 6 do an even sampling (given by `PlotPoints`) before sectioning the graphics into interesting areas to look closer at. I wonder if the v>=6 algorithm has more points because computers are assumed to be better (what's the default for `MaxRecursion` in v5.2?) or if it can afford more points because it's inherently faster? Which algorithm gives the better value for cycles?

Comment: @acl Please see updated answer.

Comment: Upvoted your comment, since I can't upvote your answer twice!

Comment: @Alexey thanks. v8 shows apparently the same behaviour as v7.

Comment: @Simon, @ acl Added description of weak points of both algorithms.

Comment: I missed this question/answer while I was away from SO.  Great stuff.  +1

Comment: Alexey, do you have any updates or new insights for version 10+?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't see significant changes in the `Plot` algorithm in version 10. One change is that now it computes at `x = 0` in `Plot[Sow[x], {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0] // Reap` while in previous versions (at least up to version 8) `Plot` avoided computing at explicit zero. The described weak points of the algorithm (see EDIT 3 and 4 and the [old post by Yaroslav Bulatov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572183/strange-sinx-graph-in-mathematica/4572266#4572266)) are not corrected (but could be corrected!), no improvements.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Plot does compute at `x = 0`, but that point will not be present in the plot. Try `Cases[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0], Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]` and compare it with your `Plot[Sow[x], {x, 0, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 0] // Reap`. It looks like there are two evaluations at the beginning and if the result of the first one is too small, the result of the second one will be used for the plot.

Comment: I was wrong about the first plotting point. It is seems to be always between the value of the first two evaluations. I was fooled by the way these numbers were displayed. I summarize my observations in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87814/18476).

Comment: @Karsten7. I'm surprised that the first point is not caught by `Sow`: `r=Reap[Plot[Sow[{x,1/x}]//Last,{x,0,10},MaxRecursion->0]];
Complement[First@Cases[r[[1]],Line[x_]:>x,Infinity],r[[2,1]]]`.

Comment: That's a consequence of the default `PlotRange -> Automatic`. Try again with `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: @Karsten7. It is nasty and unexpected: the $y$-value of this first point is obtained from `Interpolation` with `InterpolationOrder -> 1`...

Comment: @Karsten7. It's what I might, when the plot range is clipped, as it often is with `PlotRange -> Automatic` and functions like `1/x`.  It's just the intersection of the line segment with the ultimate `PlotRange`.  Note the internal points are clipped in the same fashion with `ListLinePlot[r[[2, 1]], FullOptions[r[[1]]]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am surprised again: for the developer it would be quite sufficient just to set the explicit `PlotRange`. The current behavior is unexpected because with `PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False` it is natural to expect to see the unclipped plot range but it does not happen and the user is fooled by the system: `ListLinePlot[Sort@r[[2, 1]], FullOptions[r[[1]]], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks, I have edited the answer accordingly.