# Plot has trouble plotting my function when I greatly expand the plot domain

Tags: plotting

When I make the plot

```
Plot[-x^2 E^-x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it results in two peaks around {-1, -.34}, {+1, -.34}

But when I specify a vastly expanded plot domain

```
Plot[-x^2 E^-x^2, {x, -1000, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the result looks completely different.

Why does this happen and how do I handle this situation?

Comment: Have a look at `PlotPoints`

Comment: Setting `PlotPoints->200` does fix the problem, but I do think `Plot` should be a bit better at sampling functions like this.

Comment: Sampling granularity is going to be an issue, especially in large domains where the "action" is heavily localized.

Comment: Thank for a good "warning" question!

Comment: @JasonB OK, but how would `Plot` achieve that?  What it already does it pretty advanced, I think.  What method would you propose to let it discover the interesting region when it is tiny, without making it too slow?  It seems to me that its behaviour is quite reasonable here.

Comment: @Szabolcs - (bad joke removed) You are correct, I was speaking of things I'm not an expert in.  Will leave comment for the continuity of the discussion, but your point is taken.

Comment: It is interesting to use `EvaluationMonitor` on this. After the initial sampling of 50 evenly spaced points on `{-1000,1000}` it samples 27 more points, *every one* within 2% of the ends.  (??)  Why on earth would it *not resample* near the largest spike in the data?

Comment: @JasonB I'm not just trying to make a point.  If you have any idea at all about how this might be handled better than it already is, I am really interested.  The algorithm Plot uses is simple enough that it can be reimplemented relatively quickly in Mathematica.  It's a good problem to experiment with.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Strange `Sin[x]` graph in *Mathematica*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4572183/590388)."

Comment: Related: "[How does `Plot` work?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346/280)"

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is obviously even, you need only [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) one side. Given a wide [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) using [`LogLinearPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html) helps to find and see the "action"

```
Minimize[{-x^2 E^-x^2, x > 0}, x, Reals]

(*  {-(1/E), {x -> 1}}  *)

LogLinearPlot[-x^2 E^-x^2, {x, .001, 1000}, PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Line[{{Log[1], 0}, {Log[1], -1/E}}]}]
```

[image]