# Plot glitch when plotting highly oscillatory function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I've been trying to solve an ODE as shown below. The solution is correct. However, while trying to compare the Mathematica solution to the solution I had found by hand (which was not simplified), I decided to plot the two and compare. The plot of the Mathematica result shows an odd linear jump.

```
soln2 = FullSimplify[
DSolveValue[{y''[t] + 9 y[t] == Cos[2 t], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -2}, y[t], t]]
```

> ```
> 1/5 (Cos[2 t] + 4 Cos[3 t]) - 2/3 Sin[3 t]
> ```

```
 Plot[soln, {t, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

When trying some other intervals, like 1 to 100 or 0 to 99, or seemingly anything other than 0-100, I have the periodic result I expected with no sudden linear parts.

Evaluating by hand around this area in the interval reveils correct, expected answers.

```
N[x[65]]
N[x[64.5]]
N[x[63]]
```

> ```
> 0.560737
> 0.67255
> 0.566941
> ```

```
Plot[soln, {t, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Another photo of the plot zoomed in with 0-100 and 1-100...
[image]

Is this a bug? Am I missing something? How can I trust the plot if it makes sudden bizarre mistakes like this?

I am running version 11.1.1 on MacOS sierra.

Comment: You just need some more `PlotPoints`.

Comment: Adding PlotPoints -> 10 to test, did seem to fix the issue....However why does it plot incorrectly in that specific interval? And not within 1-100 or 1-101?

Comment: As I understand it, and someone may correct me, Mathematica evaluates the function at a number of initial points.  If neighbouring groups of points are linear, then it will just plot a straight section.  If they are non-linear, it will add some more points to better define the curve.  With your highly oscillating function, it's just luck whether a few points happen to line up.  I'd recommend starting with perhaps 50 points instead of 10.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this old question: "[Strange Sin\[x\] graph in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4572183/590388)". Also strongly related: "[How does Plot work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346/280)"

Comment: Ahh yes, pratically the same. Had I considered the word strange and graphs, I probably wouldn't have had to make a new post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica evaluates the function at a number of initial points, which can be controlled with the `PlotPoints` option. If neighbouring groups of points are linear, then it will just plot a straight section. If they are non-linear, it will add some more points to better define the curve. With your highly oscillating function, it's just luck whether a few points happen to line up.

Let's construct an example to demonstrate this.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 3]
```

[image: 1]

A straight line as expected.  Now pull out the points at which the function is evaluated:

```
linear = Plot[(If[NumericQ@x, Sow@{x, x}]; x), {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 3] // Reap // Last // Last // Sort
```

And put some random points inbetween:

```
nonlinear = {(#1[[1]] + #2[[1]])/2, (#1[[1]] + #2[[1]])/
  RandomReal[{1.5, 2.5}]} & @@@ Partition[linear, 2, 1]
```

Then interpolate all the points:

```
i = Interpolation[linear~Join~nonlinear]
```

This gives a rather nonlinear plot as expected:

```
Plot[i[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: 2]

But if we put the `PlotPoints` back in, it plots as straight:

```
Plot[i[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 3, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: "If neighbouring groups of points are linear, then it will just plot a straight section. If they are non-linear, it will add some more points to better define the curve." - more specifically, this is controlled by the (formerly documented) `MaxBend` option, where you specify the maximum angle (in degrees) between the neighboring line segments; witness the difference between `Plot[(Cos[2 t] + 4 Cos[3 t])/5 - 2 Sin[3 t]/3, {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {MaxBend -> 20.}, PlotPoints -> 15]` and `Plot[(Cos[2 t] + 4 Cos[3 t])/5 - 2 Sin[3 t]/3, {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {MaxBend -> 10.}, PlotPoints -> 15]`.

Comment: @J.M. `MaxBend` is deprecated since version 6 in favor of `Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> maxBend*\[Degree]}}]` as I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348/280) (see "Edit 4" section).

Comment: @Alexey, I know about it; I just didn't have space left to fit in `"ControlValue"` in my already long comment. :D

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation with example!