# Mathematica Plot Recursion Accuracy

Tags: plotting, recursion, precision-and-accuracy

Mathematica has the neat feature to sample the domain of a plot function adaptively, using recursion on a mesh in the function's domain. The set of initial points is controlled by `PlotPoints`, the maximum number of recursions by `MaxRecursion`. The automatic recursion stops when some pre-defined accuracy limit is reached.
Now I want the recursion to become more accurate than it is with the standard settings. For this, neither a larger number of `PlotPoints` is appropriate, because is increases the mesh density everywhere, nor a larger number of `MaxRecursion`, because the recursion automatically stops as the algorithm thinks the result is accurate enough. Which option do I need to change in order to increase the desired accuracy of the recursion?

Comment: [Related, specially the edits 3 and 4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29348/5467)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to one comment, I found a satisfactory solution: The recursion accuracy can be adjusted using `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> 0.05}}`, where smaller values lead to a better accuracy and a finer mesh.

An example of 3D plots with lower and higher accuracy:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 3}, {y, -3, 0}, PlotRange -> Full,
  Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 5]
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 3}, {y, -3, 0}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
  Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> 0.05}}]
```

[image]